# json_decode to array, not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i have this variable `$a`

```
var_dump($a)

 array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "designer" [1]=> string(8) "director" [2]=> string(10) "Freelancer"}
```

i am sending this in ajax(jquery)

jquery

```
  data: 'form=<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>',
```

and in the other php file i am doing

```
$send = $_POST[form];

$b = json_encode($send);

$c = json_decode($b, true);
var_dump($c);
```

the output will be:

```
string(xx) "[\"designer\",\"director\",\"Freelancer\"]"
```

but, `echo $c[0]` show this: `[` and should be "`designer`"

Any help ?

**EDIT: already tried too**

```
$send = $_POST['form'];

$c = json_decode($send, true);

var_dump($c);

output: `null`
```

Comment: pls give us var_dump($send) result. I'm not sure 'bout what output do u mean.

Comment: updated, sorry. Var_dump $c, is correct now

Comment: `$_POST[form]` is probably incorrect, unless you are using a constant named `form`.

Comment: I don't think you need $b = json_encode($send);

Comment: the problem is caused by initial array. with this <?php 
`$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
?>` there is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$c` is actually the string "[\"designer\",\"director\",\"Freelancer\"]", and not the array `["designer", "director", "Freelancer"]`.  It looks like you're calling `json_encode` on your content twice, and `json_decode` once.

1. `form=<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>` will encode your content once,
   before sending it over the wire.
2. `$send = $_POST[form];` will get that content (already
   json_encoded).
3. `$b = json_encode($send);` will encode that same content a second
   time.
4. `$c = json_decode($b, true);` will decode it.

This will leave you with your content still encoded.  I'm not quite sure what the point of step 3 is, and it looks to me that removing it should solve your problem.

EDIT:

Since you've updated the question stating that you get `null` if you try the proposed solution, according to the [PHP documentation for json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data
>   is deeper than the recursion limit.

You should make sure that the data is set to exactly what you want, as I don't think your recursion level is too deep in this case (from the data you've given, it appears as if there is none whatsoever).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit more information.  Have you tried seeing what the value of `$send` is?

Comment: var_dump[$send] is equal to var_dump($c), with or without json_encode repeated –

Comment: So without `$b = json_encode($send)`, `$send` is null?  But with it, `$send` is "[\"designer\",\"director\",\"Freelancer\"]"?  That makes no sense... are you certain nothing else is changing?

Comment: is strange, but it's happening what you say.

Comment: ...not that this is any kind of usable solution, but... what happens if you encode twice *and* decode twice?

Comment: well, i will get again the `[ `. The initial problem.

Comment: with this <?php 
`$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
?>` there is no problem. Exists some issue in my initial array.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST[form]` already is a JSON encoded string. If you encode it again, then decode it, you'll end up with the same **string**, not an array. You don't need `$b = json_encode($send)`.

It also looks like you have Magic Quotes on. Turn them off or follow the documentation to clean your strings: http://www.php.net/magic_quotes

Also, quote your array indices!

```
$send = $_POST['form'];
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts

Comment: i already try with different ways. With the change that you suggest i simple get null.